# Azure SQL as external Sqoop metastore for HDInsight

Tags: azure, sqoop, azure-hdinsight, azure-sql-database

Good day!

Is there any documentation how to configure Azure SQL as external Sqoop metastore for HDInsight?

Typically HDInsight cluster is spawned dynamically as a compute resource and then shutdown once work is done.

That is why Sqoop job definitions need to survive cluster restarts or new clusters attached.

Ideally, external sqoop metastore should attach to new cluster during its creation process dynamically.

Regards,

-Yuriy

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, if you can create these tables below in Azure SQL or Azure MySQL and then use --meta-connect clause of Sqoop to connect to new metastore
but then there is this limitation [Sqoop on HDInsight does not close JDBC connection properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494764/)

```
CREATE TABLE SQOOP_ROOT (
version INT,
propname VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, 
propval VARCHAR(256), 
CONSTRAINT SQOOP_ROOT_unq UNIQUE (version, propname))
INSERT INTO SQOOP_ROOT
        VALUES(
          NULL,
          'sqoop.hsqldb.job.storage.version',
          '0');

           INSERT INTO SQOOP_ROOT
VALUES(
    0,
    'sqoop.hsqldb.job.info.table',
    'SQOOP_SESSIONS'
          );

  CREATE TABLE SQOOP_SESSIONS(
         JOB_NAME VARCHAR(64) ,
         PROPNAME VARCHAR(128) ,
         PROPVAL VARCHAR(1024) ,
         PROPCLASS VARCHAR(32) ,
        CONSTRAINT SQOOP_SESSIONS_unq UNIQUE
(JOB_NAME ,
PROPNAME ,
PROPCLASS)
          );
```