# Sqoop on HDInsight does not close JDBC connection properly?

Tags: azure, jdbc, sqoop, azure-hdinsight, azure-sql-database

If I use Azure SQL or Azure MySQL as metastore for SQOOP jobs there seem to be a serious bug in Sqoop on HDInsight as it does not close connection properly for saved sqoop jobs.

Here is a repo steps:

1. Use Azure SQL or Azure MySQL as SQOOP metastore and create an incremental import saved SQOOP job and then run it at the very end to get an exception:

----------------ON AZURE SQL------------

```
17/08/02 23:15:51 INFO tool.ImportTool: Updated data for job: FactOnlineSalesIncr
17/08/02 23:15:51 WARN tool.JobTool: IOException closing JobStorage: java.io.IOException: Exception committing connection
        at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.close(HsqldbJobStorage.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:314)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1745)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1732)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:5424)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6734)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6686)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1834)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1793)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1839)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.commit(SQLServerConnection.java:2016)
        at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.close(HsqldbJobStorage.java:225)
        ... 7 more
```

------ON  AZURE MYSQL-----------------:

```
17/08/03 21:01:16 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 230.3543 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
17/08/03 21:01:16 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 1947500 records.
17/08/03 21:01:16 INFO tool.ImportTool: Final destination exists, will run merge job.
17/08/03 21:01:16 INFO tool.ImportTool: Moving data from temporary directory _sqoop/4aa19d895a3c4bb08f22934dc4a69eb5_FactOnlineSales to final destination /ContosoRetailDW00/Incremental/Bzip2/FactOnlineSales
17/08/03 21:01:17 WARN azure.AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor: Disabling threads for Rename operation as thread count 0 is <= 1
17/08/03 21:01:17 INFO azure.AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor: Time taken for Rename operation is: 287 ms with threads: 0
17/08/03 21:01:17 INFO tool.ImportTool: Saving incremental import state to the metastore
17/08/03 21:01:21 INFO tool.ImportTool: Updated data for job: FactOnlineSalesIncr
17/08/03 21:01:21 WARN tool.JobTool: IOException closing JobStorage: java.io.IOException: Exception committing connection
        at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.close(HsqldbJobStorage.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:314)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1559)
        at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.close(HsqldbJobStorage.java:225)
        ... 7 more
```

Does anyone know how to get around it?

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug report with sqoop, but otherwise you need to show your code or configuration. The information you show is not sufficient to help you, but in any case it is rather suspect that the stacktrace contains `HsqldbJobStorage.close` while you are using MySQL and SQL Server; that sounds like you have configured it incorrectly.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your respond. mysql and SQL server are hosted by Microsoft Azure. There is nothing to configure there as they come packaged by Microsoft as service.

Comment: Done as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-3219